# Netty SSL hostname verification support

Tags: ssl, netty, hostname

From what I can tell, there is no 'flag' or config setting I can use to enable SSL hostname verification in Netty.  Examples I've seen add custom implementations using the ChannelFuture returned by SslHandler.handshake():

```
ChannelFuture handshakeFuture = sslHandler.handshake();
handshakeFuture.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener()
{
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception
    {
        if (future.isSuccess())
        {
            // get peer certs, verify CN (or SAN extension, or..?) against requested domain
            ...
```

I just want to make sure I'm on the right track here, and that I'm not missing a way to simply "enable" hostname verification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Java 7, you can do this by configuring the `SSLSocket` or `SSLEngine` to do it for you via the default trust manager. (This is independent of Netty.)

Something like this should work:

```java
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();

SSLParameters sslParams = new SSLParameters();
sslParams.setEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS");
sslEngine.setSSLParameters(sslParams);
```

The `SSLEngine` instance can be passed as an argument to the `SslHandler` constructor, as described in [this example](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatClientPipelineFactory.html).

The endpoint identification algorithm can be either HTTPS or LDAP. For other protocols, the HTTPS rules should be fairly sensible.

(You can of course check that it works by connecting to that host using a wrong host name, for example using a URL with the IP address instead of the host name, assuming that the certificate doesn't contain a Subject Alternative Name IP address entry for it.)

Comment: thanks so much for the quick answer.  Totally makes sense.  And, in general, thanks for all of your fantastic posts here and elsewhere.  Your name pops up everywhere regarding SSL...I've been relying heavily on your knowledge and help.  Thank you!!

Comment: These algorithm names are documented here:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#jssenames

Comment: @bruno can you go to chat please ?http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19372/room-for-royi-namir-and-bruno

Comment: So far, I can't get this to work. When I enable the HTTPS endpoint identification algorithm, the request just times out (whether the peer cert has the correct hostname or not).  I'll add more here when I know more.

Comment: I must admin I haven't tried with Netty. It would be interesting to know if you see something different with [`-Djavax.net.debug=all`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html)

Comment: One important note:  when creating the SSLEngine, you need to pass in the host and port of the target server:  createSSLEngine(targetHost, targetPort).  Otherwise you'll run into the issue documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390964/java-ssl-fatal-error-80-unwrapping-net-record-after-adding-the-https-en

Comment: @HawkeyeParker Do you have working implementation of SSL Engine?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Sorry, I do not anymore.  Haven't worked on it for a _long_ time, so I don't think I'd be any help :(

Comment: @Bruno , could you please let me know who or how [this class](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatClientPipelineFactory.html) will be instantiated ?  I created such class, but not sure how to inject this or where to inject .. Thanks

Comment: Does Netty hostname verifier uses both targetHost and targetPort to do the verification or it just uses the targetHost parameter which is passed while creating the engine as below: createSSLEngine(targetHost, targetPort). Can someone also help me to point where the actual verification is being done ?