# SSL handshake with Play having mismatch on hostnames

Tags: scala, ssl, playframework, sslhandshakeexception

We are using Play 2.5 + Scala and need to use SSL to connect to remote client using https.

The issue is the certificate that we got from client has CN  something like `api.*.*.*.net`

but the actual URL we are trying to hit contains an IP Address :
`https://123.234.34.56/service/resource/operation...`

Since the common name in the certificate and the hostname(ipAddress) in the URL do not match , we are seeing the below error.

`SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present`

So I tried to implement HostnameVerifier as shown below in Scala but this code is not being picked up by Play or Netty

```
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier()
        {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session)
            {
               // custom logic here to match hostname and IpAddress
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I have no idea why Play/Netty is not picking it up during runtime, but we are hitting the remote client using Play WS :

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WS 
WS.url(url).get()...
```

I am also thinking of trying the solution mentioned here : 
[Netty SSL hostname verification support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315623/netty-ssl-hostname-verification-support)

but not sure if I need to implement a ChannelFactory as per the above link as shown here `http://netty.io/3.10/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatClientPipelineFactory.html`

Also I have seen somewhere else in SO posts that :

***If the host name in the certificate doesn't resolve to the address, the server is mis-configured. Nevertheless, you should be able to alter your local DNS resolution to point that name to this IP address in your /etc/hosts file (if under Linux, or its Windows equivalent***

I have no idea how to achieve this programatically in Java/Scala

Any help would be much appreciated !

Thanks

Suresh

Comment: @Bruno could you please take a look at my query above. ? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "hosts" fix looks like this:

1. Add a line like the following to your `hosts` file ([instructions for Windows or Linux here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/))

   ```
   123.234.34.56 api.a.b.c.net
   ```
2. Now connect to the server using the hostname "api.a.b.c.net", rather than its IP address
3. Because of the `hosts` override, your machine will not do a DNS lookup for this name, but will use that IP address. However, the SSL client will be satisfied that the hostname matches the cert and the error should go away.

For the HostnameVerifier fix, you need to follow the instructions in the answer you linked to. The Netty SSL client doesn't use the static global config that you are currently using.

Comment: HI @Rich, thanks for responding,  I have no access to the `hosts` file.  Is there a way that we can update the hosts file programatically in Java/Scala ? Also I have implemented a similar code as shown here `http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/SecureChatClientPipelineFactory.html` but netty is not picking up this code during runtime/startuo Thanks

Comment: There is no way to update `hosts` from within Java/Scala, it is an O/S configuration task.